# Looping nested through a nested JSON Object and saving values in an array list

Tags: java, android, json

I  have a JSON object as the one shown below

```
{"PAYLOAD":[{"pid":"4","title":"Kyamaiko Flats","long":"36.764880000","lat":"-1.342980800","volume":125,"value":"10000","active":"Y","contractor":"SS mehta and Sons","subContractor":"Kamau Njoro","cp":[{"contactPerson":"Njoroge","designation":"Architect"},{"contactPerson":"John","designation":"Quantity suveyor"}],"lastvisit":"2 months ago ","nextvisit":"10/12/2013 ""image_url":"http:\\www.someurl.net\images\avator.png"}]}
```

To get the Values I use the code below:

```
try{

                JSONArray  mot = json.getJSONArray("PAYLOAD");
                    for(int i=0;i<mot.length();i++){                        
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();        
                        JSONObject e = mot.getJSONObject(i);
                        map.put(KEY_NAME_ID, e.getString(KEY_NAME_ID));
                        map.put(KEY_NAME, e.getString(KEY_NAME));
                        map.put(KEY_LAT, e.getString(KEY_LAT));
                        map.put(KEY_LON, e.getString(KEY_LON));
                        map.put(KEY_VOLUME, e.getString(KEY_VOLUME));
                        map.put(KEY_VALUE, e.getString(KEY_VALUE));
                        map.put(KEY_ACCOUNT_STATUS, e.getString(KEY_ACCOUNT_STATUS));
                        map.put(KEY_CONTRACTOR, e.getString(KEY_CONTRACTOR));
                        map.put(KEY_SUB_CONTRACTOR, e.getString(KEY_SUB_CONTRACTOR));

                        JSONArray  cp = json.getJSONArray(KEY_CONTACT_PERSON);

                        for(int j=0;j<cp.length();j++)
                        {
                        HashMap<String, String> map_cp = new HashMap<String, String>();     
                        JSONObject f = cp.getJSONObject(j);
                        map_cp.put(KEY_CONTACT_PERSON_NAME, f.getString(KEY_CONTACT_PERSON_NAME));
                        map_cp.put(KEY_CONTACT_PERSON_DESIGNATION, f.getString(KEY_CONTACT_PERSON_DESIGNATION));
                         }
                        map.put(KEY_LAST_VISIT, e.getString(KEY_LAST_VISIT));
                        map.put(KEY_NEXT_VISIT, e.getString(KEY_NEXT_VISIT));
                        map.put(KEY_IMAGE_URL, e.getString(KEY_IMAGE_URL));
                        displaylist.add(map);
                    }       
              }catch(JSONException e)      {
                  Util.LogFailedVisits ("JSON Exception "+e.toString(),mDID);
              }
```

I want to Pass the values from the second JSONObject and add them to a HashMap and subsequentlty to an Arraylist so I can be able to pass them to another Fragment.. Is this the best way to do it? or How would I best pass this values to another Fragment?

Answer (score 0):

use `Fragment.setArguments()` to pass a Bundle instance. Inside the Bundle you can put a `Serializable` obect (your `Collection` of `HashMap`, for instance)

Comment: If I do That then I get the error: The method setArguments(Bundle) in the type Fragment is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>)

Answer (score 0):

You have to first create a Bundle, then add the serializable hashmap into the bundle, then set the arguments of the fragment as show below:

```
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable('key', 'value');

    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
```